# What is the use of type (Bash builtins)?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I came across a command in Bash script in which I found:

```
find /var/log/abcd -type f
```

The above command was in context of cleaning the log files.
I know what `find` does.

After having seen `-type f`, I looked manual page for it.
I got to see it in man page of **BASH_BUILTINS(1)**

The description of -f flag under `type` command is :-

```
The -f option suppresses shell function lookup, as with the command builtin.
```

Following are my questions:

1. What is the use of `type` ?
2. What is the significance of `-f` flag?
3. What is the use of using `type` with `find` command?

**[EDIT]:-** After having read all the comments and answers till now, I would like to mention the cause for my misinterpretation of `-type option in command find` Vs `type command` .
This all happened because I was assuming and till date have seen only the short options(Tests in case of the `find` command) with a **single minus sign '-'**, example, `ls -l`. Most of the times I have seen long options with **double minus sign '--'** , example, `ls --version`.

Comment: The `type` builtin command is not used by `find`. The `-type` option to `find` does something else. See `help type` and `man find` to get your answers.

Comment: This specific misinterpretation is very specific and unlikely going to help others as a question

Comment: Why downvoting? While the question does show the OP doesn't know much about Unix, that's not right to downvote a question on those grounds. Akshay even went as far as reading a man page which most people asking questions here do not do.

Comment: please consider rephrase your question title, because your current title is preventing people who really is looking for the use of bash built-in 'type' from getting accurate answer..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In this case `type` has nothing to do with the bash built-in `type`, but more on that later on.

### A little about *"type"*

The BASH built-in `type` command gives you information about commands. Thus:

```
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
```

The syntax is:

```
type [-tap] [name ...]
```

- `-t`: print only type, if found
- `-a`: print all occurrences of the command, both built-in and other.
- `-p`: print the disk file that would be executed on call to command, or nothing.

If we look at `time`, `kill` and `cat` as an example:

```
$ type time kill cat
time is a shell keyword
kill is a shell builtin
cat is /bin/cat

$ type -t time kill cat
keyword
builtin
file

$ type -a time kill cat
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
kill is a shell builtin
kill is /bin/kill
cat is /bin/cat

$ type -ta time kill cat
keyword
file
builtin
file
file
```

Now, this specify that if you are in a Bash shell and type `time some_cmd`, the bash builtin `time` is used. To use the system `time` you can do `/usr/bin/time some_cmd`.

One way often used to ensure that the system, and not built-in, command is used is by using `which`.

```
tt=$(which time)
```

and then use `$tt` to call system `time`.

---

### The command in question

In this case the `-type` is an option to the command `find`. The option takes one argument of by which specify the type of entity. Example

```
find . -type f  # File
find . -type d  # Directory
```

There are more, check `man find` for the rest.

To search for the specific option you can do (whilst in man):

```
/^\s*-typeEnter
```

Then use `n` for *next* until you find it.

---

### A little about shell command

*This is a bit of a personal interpretation.*

Some of the things worth mentioning, in this specific case, are commands, options, arguments and pipes.

This is somewhat loosely used, but in my vocabulary we have in short:

- command: a *program* or *built-in*.
- parameter: an entity after the command word.
- option: an ***optional*** parameter.
- argument: a required parameter.

In a command specification square brackets are used to specify options and, optionally less/greater then, used to specify arguments. Thus:

```
foo [-abs] [-t <bar>] <file> ...
foo [-abs] [-t bar] file ...
```

Gives `-a` `-b` and `-s` as optional parameters, and `file` a required one.
`-t` is optional, but if specified takes the required argument `bar`. Dots represent that it can take several files.

This is no exact specification, and often `man` or `help` is required to be sure.

Positioning of arguments options and input can often be mixed up, but it is generally best to keep to a position based approach as some systems does not handle mixed positioning of arguments. As an example:

```
chmod -R nick 722 foo
chmod nick 722 foo -R
```

Both work on some systems, whilst the latter does not on other.

---

In your exact command all parameters belongs to `find` – thus if you wonder about a property `man find` is the correct place to look. In cases where you need to look at man pages for the shell etc. could be in e.g.:

```
find . $(some command)
find . `some command`
find . $some_var
find . -type f -exec some_command {} \;
find . -type f | some_command
...
```

The `-exec` is a special one where `-exec some_command {} \;` are all parameters given to `find`, but the `some_command {} \;` part is expanded, within `find` to `some_command string_of_found_entity`.

---

### Further on

- quoting
- expansion
- command substitution
- and so much more

[You might find this useful](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html).

Comment: Very Informative.

Answer (score 8):

You shoul look in `man find`, not in `help type` or `man bash`. `type` in `find` will specify what file type you need:

```
   -type c
          File is of type c:

          b      block (buffered) special

          c      character (unbuffered) special

          d      directory

          p      named pipe (FIFO)

          f      regular file

          l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the
                 -follow option is in effect, unless the symbolic link  is
                 broken.  If you want to search for symbolic links when -L
                 is in effect, use -xtype.

          s      socket

          D      door (Solaris)
```

And builtin `type` is completely different thing and it's NOT the one is used inside `find`.

Answer (score 0):

You looked to the wrong manual page, this isn't the `type -f` command but `find -type f` option which is quite different, have a look to the `find` manual for proper explanations.

Answer (score 0):

`-type f` tells find to only print files of type f ie plain files, not directories, not symbolic links and not device files. `man find` then search for `-f` option.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right manual page you are looking at. You should be using

```
man find
```

that will tell you that with `-type f` the `-type` predicate selects only the regular files.